# Modifying Sass Bootstrap Variables for Adaptive Templates (Mobile or Desktop Only)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-sass

I'm working on a site that has chosen to go the adaptive route (separate mobile and desktop templates) on many of the site pages, rather than responsive. It is still using Bootstrap on these templates and loading all the css for the different Bootstrap breakpoints. My hope is that I can use the Sass Bootstrap variables (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) to remove a lot of the unnecessary css. To complicate matters, the mobile templates were coded using the sm classes rather than xs. For example, col-sm-16 (they customized Bootstrap to be 16 columns instead of 12).

So, is there a way to modify the Sass variables in order to output only the necessary css for mobile and desktop templates respectively? I'm mainly looking to cut down on the amount of css that has to load in order to optimize performance.

One other thing you should maybe know is that we're only using the small breakpoint for desktop as well. I've modified the vars as such:

```
$screen-xs:                     640px;
// //** Deprecated `$screen-xs-min` as of v3.2.0
// $screen-xs-min:              $screen-xs !default;
// //** Deprecated `$screen-phone` as of v3.0.1
// $screen-phone:               $screen-xs-min !default;

// // Small screen / tablet
// //** Deprecated `$screen-sm` as of v3.0.1
$screen-sm:                     640px;
// $screen-sm-min:              $screen-sm !default;
// //** Deprecated `$screen-tablet` as of v3.0.1
// $screen-tablet:              $screen-sm-min !default;

// // Medium screen / desktop
// //** Deprecated `$screen-md` as of v3.0.1
$screen-md:                     640px;
// $screen-md-min:              $screen-md !default;
// //** Deprecated `$screen-desktop` as of v3.0.1
// $screen-desktop:             $screen-md-min !default;

// // Large screen / wide desktop
// //** Deprecated `$screen-lg` as of v3.0.1
$screen-lg:                     9999px;
```

Is there a better way when you consider that I'm trying to remove the xs styles for the desktop stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in Bootstrap3 give you an easy way to adjust resulting CSS code, but not to choose what you need to include and what not. Only solution is to edit Bootstrap's *.scss files and remove unneeded code. For example, try removing few "make-grid(...)" lines from bootstrap/_grid.scss .

Comment: Thank you, Maris. I had just started looking at this same file you recommended. I was trying to avoid changes to the core for maintainability, but adjusting a few lines here shouldn't cause too many problems. I will likely utilize some sort of @if to avoid having to duplicate _grid.scss for the various outputs. Thanks again!

Comment: Just wanted to add that since we're only using the sm classes, I should just be able to comment out the other media queries and make-grid includes in _grid.scss.